# in a Listview on list item click how can i get the title(the name ) of the selected item? android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

I have listview that binds from sqlite and groups by KEY_TITLE(field) so i need to get the name of the item that is clicked

```
   @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,detail.class);

        i.putExtra(DatabaseIN.KEY_TITLE,SOMETHING THAT I NEED!);

        //startActivity(i);
        startActivityForResult(i,ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }
```

// maybe something like this string selectedIteme = l.getSelectedItem().getSOMETNIG?

Comment: I cannot get the rowId as i used before because of the group by that i have at least i thing so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this tutorial might help you
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

you can pick the selected item value like this

```
 @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Xyz.class);
i.putExtra("abc", c.getString(1));
startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: yes but not for the list i am using it for autocompletetextview

Comment: i have edited my answer for cusror adapter it should also work for autocomplete text

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your onClick method..

```
Map<String, String> selection = (Map<String, String>) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
 String count = selection.get("count");
 String title = selection.get("title");
```

Comment: my sqlite table hast _ID KEY_TITLE KEY_DATAS KEY_BODY KEY_DATE_TIME 
and on the above code(yours) it happens error